# informix update query with joins

Tags: sql, informix

i am tryng to update one field of table using the values present in the other table, but it is giving "201: A syntax error has occurred."

```
UPDATE  altr_destination
SET     ad.store_num = sx.new_store_num
FROM    altr_destination ad ,   store_xref sx
WHERE   ad.store_num = sx.old_store_num 
AND     ad.store_num = 9999 ;
```

Thanks,
Utkarsh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use implicit join syntax(comma separated) , use the proper syntax of joins!

It can be done with a correlated sub query as well :

```
UPDATE  altr_destination ad
SET     ad.store_num =(SELECT sx.new_store_num
                       FROM store_xref sx
                       WHERE   ad.store_num = sx.old_store_num)
WHERE ad.store_num = 9999 ;
```

I think update with join doesn't work on older versions of informix , at least that's what I saw when I looked for it.

Comment: You're right: Informix's [UPDATE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1254.htm) statement does not support join notations.  They're not a part of the SQL-2003 standard (or earlier versions of the standard, therefore); I don't know whether they've been added to the standard since then.